# How to reset iTerm2 Window/Tab Title when disconnecting from remote host?

Tags: macos, bash, iterm

I have my `bash_profile` on my Mac and the remote computers I connect to setup to automatically put the hostname in the window's (or tab's) title area.

*A bash shell on my local machine*

[image: Local Apple Account]

*A remote host name "Socrates"; also a bash shell.*

[image: Remote Shell Window]

The problem is, when I exit (and disconnect) from the remote host, the window title stays with the host name of the remote.  So, in effect, I'm on the local Apple bash shell with the remote name.  To fix it, I do one of the following:

- close the window and open a new one
- re-source the `.bash_profile` (`. ~/.bash_profile`)
- create a new sub shell by issuing the command `bash` (not desirable at all)

**How can I have this done *automatically* so that when I exit a remote shell, the title goes back to the original host name so I know what host I'm actually connected to?**

Note, the previously asked question, [Terminal displays directory of previous SSH location even when not running SSH](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/175326/119271) didn't adequately address the issue because the solution was to modify `.bash_logoff` which only worked for login shells.

Comment: Not sure about this not being a dpulicate, the answer on the other post also offers a solution without using `.bash_logout`. And the answer you've posted below would be equally valid for the other question as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to this problem is solved by using Terminal Control Codes (Esc 22 and 23) and  placing four simple lines in `.bashrc` of the remote host:

```
# ~/.bashrc
#
# Set the Terminal Title

echo -ne "\033[22;0t"                     #Save Title on Stack
echo -ne "\033]0;${HOSTNAME}\007"         #Set New Title

trap 'echo -ne "\033[23;0t"'  EXIT        #Reset Title Window
```

### How This Works

By using the [Terminal Escape Sequence Codes 22 and 23](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Miscellaneous), we can save and retrieve the original title.  The `trap` function (`man bash`) will execute a command when a signal is received; in this case upon exit.

Now, when I exit (terminate) the remote host, the title reverts back to the proper host name.

#### Why .bashrc?

I want to have this available to me whether I log into the host from a remote machine (most common) or when I am local to it.  `.bash_profile` is read for an interactive login shell and `.bashrc` is read for an interactive, non-login shell (local) is started.

To ensure that this is the same for both conditions, I include the following in my `.bash_profile`:

```
# run a .bashrc file if it exists.

test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do what most people do, set the window title as part of the prompt?

Comment: @MarcWilson - and when you exit the session?

Comment: And then the previous prompt controls.

Comment: Unless you restart the session, it doesn't change the title.  Have you tested it?

Comment: Of course.  How else would you expect it to work? Bash evaluates PROMPT_COMMAND every time it displays the prompt.  This also allows you to have the same shell configuration on the remotes as on the primary host.  For myself, I use ksh93, which allows you to substitute and perform alias expansions in $PS1 directly, but the results are the same.